# Flutter Firebase Cloud function can not be called

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am getting an error whilst using Firebase Cloud Functions when I try to call a callable function from Flutter.

```
flutter: caught generic exception
flutter: PlatformException(functionsError, Firebase function failed with exception., {message: NOT FOUND, code: NOT_FOUND})
```

Here is how I try to call the cloud function with using cloud_functions: ^0.4.2+3

```
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
      _check(String id) async {
        HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance
            .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'checkUserFavorites');
        try {
          final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(
            <String, dynamic>{
              'id': id,
            },
          );
          print(result.data);
        } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
          print('caught firebase functions exception');
          print(e.code);
          print(e.message);
          print(e.details);
        } catch (e) {
          print('caught generic exception');
          print(e);
        }
      }
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the cloud function itself. When they run in region('europe-west1') or region('europe-west2') they fail with PlatformException(3840, The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format., null) or PlatformException(functionsError, Firebase function failed with exception., {message: NOT FOUND, code: NOT_FOUND}). Are Callable functions not supported across all regions? When not defining a region the function run as expected without any issues or errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have experienced similar issues, and with few days of debugging and experimenting I found the solution only after studying the source code of [Cloud Functions Plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions).

When you deploy Firebase Cloud function, you can choose any region of preference (closer to your application the better). For example

```
// using DigitalOcean spaces
exports.generateCloudImageUrl = functions
    .region('europe-west3')
    .https.onCall((reqData, context) => {
...
}
```

When you want to call this function from Flutter app, you must specify the region, otherwise all goes to `us-central1` which is default. See example code on how to use a function deployed in a specific region

```
final HttpsCallable generateCloudImageUrl = new CloudFunctions(region: "europe-west3")
      .getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'generateCloudImageUrl');

// NB! if you initialize with 'CloudFunctions.instance' then this uses 'us-central1' as default region!
```

see [cloud_function source](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/5b87a692ac7735b004ce1b301f5a2f199c8531b0/packages/cloud_functions/cloud_functions/lib/src/cloud_functions.dart#L19) for init.

Update, as of [recent release](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/#specifying-regions), you can initialize as below;

```
FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: "europe-west3").httpsCallable(
            "generateCloudImageUrl",
            options:
                HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30)));
```

Comment: doing all that still didn't fix the issue for me untill i added 
  <script src=". . ./firebasejs/7.16.0/firebase-functions.js"></script> to /web/index.html

Comment: as of March 2021:  
[Docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/#specifying-regions)    So you could initialize as  
`final FirebaseFunctions _firebaseFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west3');`

Comment: thnx @goldensoju , just updated the answer by your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud functions are supported in the regions that you are currently running them, according to the [Cloud Functions Location Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations), but not in all regions.

According to what you shared in the comments, I would say that there are 3 cenarios to your issue:

- `europe-west1`: The function is probably out of date, since you are getting an unespected data format error, which suggest that it expects different data/format than your default function.
- `europe-west2`: The function is not deployed in this region, this is hinted in the error message `message: NOT FOUND`.
- Default Function (unknown region): This is the most recent version of the function, on a region different than `europe-west1` and `europe-west2`, and it accepts the call 
  with the data in the format that you are sending.

**NOTE**: You can check which regions you currently have your cloud function deployed on the cloud functions dashboard, as you can see on the example image below:

[image]

Also, I suspect that the default region you using is `us-central1`, since according to the documentation:

> By default, functions run in the `us-central1` region

To fix your issue, I suggest that you redeploy your current version of the function to the europe-west regions that you intend to use.

Comment: If I don't configure a default it will is us-central1 indeed. My DB is located at europe-west3. All my other functions are deployed to europe-west1 and they work as expected. However deploying a callable function in europe-west1 does not work. I have now used the default us-central1 and it works. Let me wonder if callable functions are supported in europe-west1.

Comment: As I commented in the answer, `europe-west1` is listed as a region that supports cloud functions, all those regions support all types of functions, including callable functions, so I wouldn't say it's an issue with the region itself. Do you get any errors or logs on that deploy so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: When deployed to europe-west1 I can't even see LOGS when the function is called.

Comment: try completetly deleting your instance of the function in that region and re-deploy it.

Comment: Happy to try again but already done this multiple times. Will keep you posted!

Comment: Nothing is happening when deploy to europe-west1 when the function is called. Even the LOGS don't show anything.

Comment: i'm having similar issue. tried delete-redeploy few times, even logs are not showing.  issue began after changing the region from default us to europe-west3

Comment: strangely, when I switch back to default region `us-central1`, it works fine....

Comment: @guleryuz Since you and Ben are both experiencing the same issue on the same region, I would say that this is probably an issue in this specific region in GCP. I would suggest that you open a ticket on Google's [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) system so that they can work on fixing it, as they might not even be aware of it. I will also add this to the answer above, so that the community can be aware of this without coming to the comments.

Comment: actually, it is not region issue, I just found the reason with a simple solution, I'll append with code example in the answer below.

Comment: @guleryuz I have the exact problem, anything other than `us-central1` (the default), the cloud function does not get called and there are no logs. Would you post the answer as you said?

Comment: the answer with solution is already posted, see accepted answer right under the question.  if it works for you, then plz remember to vote up ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons this error mostly happens:

### 1. Call the correct function:

Make sure to call the correct function in its full name (visible when you start a local emulator). Espacially if you have additional exports of files in your `index.js` file make sure to call the export name as well.

Syntax: `serverLocation-optionalExportParent-yourFunction`

Example: `us-central1-post_functions-updateShare`

Note that the server location can also be [configured in your instance](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/#emulator-usage)

### 2. Emulator: Same WIFI

Make sure to be connected to the same wifi, when using the emulator. Otherwise, any call will end in **unvailablity** resulting in

```
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/unavailable] UNAVAILABLE
```

### 3. Emulator: Correct host configuration

To connect to a physical device the host at all emulators at your `firebase.json` must be configured: Simply add `"host": "0.0.0.0"`.

Now the host in flutter needs to be your **ip-adress of the computer**. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67975075/11003497)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in addition to the regional issue, what really solved to me was to include the script below in index.html:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```