# Flutter firebase connect to emulator from real device

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Hi I am currently using firebase's local emulator and flutter. However, I am using a real device and not a simulator therefore I do not know how to connect to my laptops localhost. I am currently using this code

```
  // [Firestore | localhost:8080]
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = const Settings(
    host: "localhost:8080",
    sslEnabled: false,
    persistenceEnabled: false,
  );

  // [Authentication | localhost:9099]
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.useEmulator("http://localhost:9099");

  FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(
      origin: "http://localhost:5001"
  );

  // [Storage | localhost:9199]
  await FirebaseStorage.instance.useEmulator(
    host: "localhost",
    port: 9199,
  );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I fixed the problem by these two steps:

firebase.json:

```
{
  ...
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0", <--- Adding host
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

flutter main.dart:

```
const String localIp = "You local ip goes here";



FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = const Settings(
  host: localIp+":8080",
  sslEnabled: false,
  persistenceEnabled: false,
);

await FirebaseAuth.instance.useEmulator("http://"+localIp+":9099");

FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(
    origin: "http://"+localIp+":5001"     
);

await FirebaseStorage.instance.useEmulator(
  host: localIp,
  port: 9199,
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Remember to consider the region if your local functions are set up to a specific region:
`FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1').useFunctionsEmulator('192.168.50.43', 5001);` cloud_functions@^3.0.3 syntax

Comment: No `http://...` is actually needed. Your IP address is already enough!

Comment: I do not found the firebase.json file in my project directory. Can you help?