# '[firebase_functions/unavailable] UNAVAILABLE Exception' using Firebase Local Emulator w/ Cloud functions

Tags: flutter, firebase, exception, firebase-tools

I'm trying to use the Functions Emulator but it is causing problems when I try to use it in my Flutter app. I am currently on the free plan, but I have read that Functions for Local Emulator are available.

When I create my function (using node v2) like this:

```js
exports.getBooks = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
...
}
```

and then make an HTTP request from my browser, I get the desired result. However, when I change it to

```js
const {onCall, onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = admin.initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore(app);

exports.getBooks = onCall(async (request) => {
...
}
```

and then make the function call from my Flutter app, I get an UNAVAILABLE exception.

I have added the following code in my main.dart:

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);

FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
```

and this code in my app:

```dart
final HttpsCallable getBooks = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('getBooks');
final response = await getBooks.call();
// OR without .call(): final response = await getBooks();
```

However, the `.call()` method is causing the issue.

I have added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `<application>` in my AndroidManifest.xml, but it does not resolve the issue.

Do you have any idea on how to make this work?

#### Related Links

[N/A]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the localhost with 10.0.2.2.

Also, if your functions are deployed in any specific region then specify the region too like follow.

```
FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1')
  .useFunctionsEmulator('10.0.2.2', 5001);

FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1').httpsCallable('getBooks');
```

The above changes should work.

Comment: Your solution unfortunately did not work.
This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67973536/flutter-firebase-connect-to-emulator-from-real-device did. I had to change the host IP in the 'emulators' field in firebase.json to 0.0.0.0. Thank you for the help though

Comment: Oh yes. For me also the emulator IP for functions and ip provided in code should be same. Thanks